# NodeJs http status exception handling

Tags: node.js, express, exception

I have created nodejs + express application. Now in my application when exception caught errors are send as follows

```
app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
      if(!req.params.token){
        return res.status(403).send('Access token not provided');
      }

      //do something here
    });
```

Instead of sending **res.status(403).send('Access token not provided');** can I send something like this

**exception.js**

```
class Forbidden {
    constructor(message,stack = null){
        this.code = 403;
        this.message = message
        this.stack = stack;
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```
var httpForbidden = require('exception.js');

app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
if(!req.params.token){
    return new httpForbidden ('Access token not provided');
}

//do something here
});
```

And also how can I caught all exceptions in once place ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
class httpError {}

class httpForbidden extends httpError {
  constructor(message, stack = null) {
    super();
    this.code = 403;
    this.message = message
    this.stack = stack;
  }
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.params.token) {
    throw new httpForbidden('Access token not provided');
  }
  ...
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err instanceof httpError) {
    return res.status(err.code).send(err.message);
  }
  res.sendStatus(500);
});
```

This uses an Express [error handling middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) that will check if the error that got thrown is an instance of `httpError` (which would be the superclass of all the HTTP error classes that you'd want to create) and, if so, would generate a particular response according to the code and the message (or generate a generic 500 error response otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

I like to create a separate function, along with other utility functions ( say in **lib.js**), which creates a properly formatted JSON response object and selects the appropriate logger to log response depending upon the HTTP status code.

### lib.js

```
var logger = require("./loggger");

module.exports.sendResponse = function (res,code,message,data) {

    if(code<100 || code>599) {
        throw new Error("response cannot be sent. Invalid http-code was provided.");
    }
    var responseLogger = code>=500 ? logger.error : logger.debug;

    var responseObject = {
        "code" : code,
        "message" : message
    };

    if(data) {
        responseObject.data = data;
    }

    responseLogger(responseObject);

    res.status(code).json(responseObject);
};
```

### app.js

```
var lib = require("./lib");

/*
Relevant Express server code
 */
app.get('/data', function (req,res) {

    if(!req.params.token){
        return lib.sendResponse(res,403,"Access token not provided");
    }

    // Rest of business logic
});
```

**Note : You can write your own logging functionality, but I strongly suggest to build it upon some standard logging library like `winston`)**

Answer (score 1):

**Below method is deprecated as the boom is changes to [@hapi/boom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/boom),**

https://hapi.dev/family/boom/?v=8.0.1

here you find whole documentation of @hapi/boom library

-----**deprecated**-------

You can use boom library instead, which provides a set of utilities for returning HTTP errors

HTTP 4xx Errors

> Boom.badRequest([message], [data])
>
> Boom.unauthorized([message],[scheme], [attributes])

HTTP 5xx Errors

> Boom.badImplementation([message], [data]) - (alias: internal)
>
> Boom.notImplemented([message], [data])

for more api documentation visit [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/boom)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
res.code(403).json({message: '...', stack: '...'});
```

and send whatever you want. But you do it with calling methods on the response object.

> And also how can I caught all exceptions in once place ?

Very bad idea. You should handle all errors where they happen so that you can still have some context to handle them in a reasonable way. Otherwise you can just throw exceptions and return 500 errors.

Comment: "res.code(403).json({message: '...', stack: '...'});" this is what Im doing right now. Instead of that I want to send "new httpForbidden ('Access token not provided');"